# Why LongListSelector ItemTemplate Doesn't Show Anything?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I need a pivot page that in every pivot page there is a longlistselector to list the data...

this is the code that i write when i create a simple pivot page

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="all">
            <phone:LongListSelector Name="AllNotes"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="White"
                                    Margin="0,17,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="aaaa">

                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

but there isn't anything in the pivot item

i mean by defining a data template and then a stackpanel, there is nothing shown in the pivot item

can you help me ti figure out whats happening exactly?

Comment: You need bind/add data to longlistselector

Comment: I know that, even after binding data there isn't anything shown there, by the way, as you see, i define a stack panel, but it doesn't shown!!! :|

Comment: there is no bounded data in your example, in the same manner you can ask a crystal ball for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem in the way that I don't believe it!

The answer is that we have to start writing the application in the base of Pivot Application !!!

That I don't believe this in the first place!

But Thank You Anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

here is my binding code

```
<phone:Pivot Title="MY NOTEPAD"
                 Background="DarkCyan">
        <!-- All Notes -->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="all">
            <phone:LongListSelector Name="FirstListBox"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding AllNotes}"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,17,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Memory}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

now what you think about it?